# Why is the `question` property in the API not reachable and why is questionBank not rendering?

Tags: reactjs, json, async-await

*Just to let you know, I don't yet know how to use class based components, setState, etc. I also don't know how to use other things in async js like axios or whatever else yet. This is what I can do below. Very basic.*

This is App.js:

```html
import Questions from './components/Questions.js'
import './index.css'
import {React, useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function App() {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
      async function getQuestions(){
        const response = await fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5")
        const data = await response.json()
        setQuestions(() => data.results)
      }
      getQuestions()
    }, [])

  const questionBank = questions.map(singleQuestion => {
    <Questions 
      question={singleQuestion.question}
    />
  })

  console.log(questions[0].question)

  return (
    <div>
       {questionBank}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

For some reason, `console.log(questions[0].question)` when typed in to the editor and saved for the first time, it shows a question from the api. But after refreshing the page it doesn't show a question but it says: `App.js:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'question')` But when I just do this: `console.log(questions[0])`, it shows the first object of the array from the API no problem. I'm confused.

Also, `questionBank` doesn't render at all for some reason.

This is Questions.js:

```html
import React from 'react'

export default function Questions(props){
    return(
        <div>
            <p>{props.question}</p>
            <br />
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is index.js:

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM  from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
root.render(
    <App />
)
```

Comment: Is the API returning proper results?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to improve in your code (such as maybe make a `useCallback` out of `function getQuestions` in the `useEffect`), but the biggest issue is that you are not properly returning JSX from the map method.

Your code:

```
const questionBank = questions.map(singleQuestion => {
  <Questions 
    question={singleQuestion.question}
  />
})
```

notice the curly braces `{` & `}`. The proper code:

```
const questionBank = questions.map(singleQuestion => (
  <Questions 
    question={singleQuestion.question}
  />
))
```

After this change, your code should work properly.

Also, your console.log will cause errors, because you are `console.log`ging before even fetching theses questions, so obviously `questions[0]` is `undefined`.

---

More improvements to the code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([]);

  const getQuestions = useCallback(async () => {
    const response = await fetch("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5");
    const data = await response.json();
    setQuestions(data.results);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getQuestions();
  }, [getQuestions]);

  const questionBank = questions.map((singleQuestion) => (
    <Questions question={singleQuestion.question} />
  ));

  return <div>{questionBank}</div>;
}
```